# Newly formatted Windows 7 SP1 laptop won't load up redirected user profiles?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7

I recently formatted a Dell laptop and reinstalled Windows 7 SP1 on it.  We have redirected profiles on our network and when the users of these laptops login, the icons from their redirected profiles do not show up on their desktops.

Comment: Are you using redirected folders or roaming profiles or a combination of both? Also, is the newly formated laptop correctly picking up the group policy that sets these settings?

Comment: I found out that one problem was that the computer wasn't taken off the domain properly before formatting it...